# Check if ip is in range Python on Raspberry

Tags: python, ip, raspberry-pi

Im trying to solve my problem for 2 days now. But what ever i'm trying it won't work.

The raspberry's ip: 192.168.1.129

```
import socket
import fcntl
import struct
#import time

def get_ip_address(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
        s.fileno(),
        0x8915,  # SIOCGIFADDR
        struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])
    )[20:24])

#print get_ip_address('lo')
#print get_ip_address('eth0')
#print get_ip_address('wlan0')

shortip = get_ip_address('wlan0')[:3]
#print shortip

if shortip in range(1, 255):    
   print get_ip_address('wlan0')
else:
   print 'No connection'
```

When I untag the print get_ip_address('wlan0') i get a result: 192.168.1.129

When I untag the shortip i get a result: 192

That shoult be in the range.

But i'm only get the result "No connection"

Any ideas why this would be happening?
Thank you!

Comment: `shortip` is a string. As such it will never be `in` any `range`. Convert it to an `int` before doing the comparison.

Comment: Thanks... this will work! I really appreciate your help.